# jQuery: Remove Div after 2 combined animations done?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a jQuery line that execute 2 animations, what i want is to remove the `#flasher` DIV after sliding it up by my current code. How to add a callback in this bunch of brackets?

here is my code:

```
$("#flasher").animate({opacity: 1.0}, 6000).animate({"top": "-=30px"},"slow");
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#flasher").animate({opacity: 1.0}, 6000)
.animate({"top": "-=30px"},"slow",function(){
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

this should to it

```
$("#flasher").animate({opacity: 1.0}, 6000).animate({"top": "-=30px"},"slow", function() {
    $("#flasher").remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add callback function as the next parameter in last call to animate. The [animate api page](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) has some examples.